# Android GPS: average location resolution time

Tags: gps, android, geolocation

What is the average location resolution time on a SmartPhone(Android) GPS?

Assumptions : 
 The user is under the open sky.

Comment: You might have a look at this related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43617/

Comment: @julien I have read that question before. does not have what I am looking for. Thanks for the linkk.

Answer (score 2):

This can depend on a wide variety of factors. eg what make/model of phone, what GPS chipset it has, what version Android, what software, whether you are using assisted GPS, how long since GPS was last used etc.

Probably what makes most difference is assisted GPS. If the phone has a data connection (eg wifi or 3G), then it can download the current GPS almanac, and receive the precise time. Also it can use wifi and mobile networks to calculate an approximate location, which makes getting a GPS lock much quicker.

In my experience of Android phones: with assisted GPS, it usually gets a GPS location within 10 seconds. Without assisted GPS, this can take about 1 minute or so. Possibly much longer if it has been a long time since GPS was last used, or if it has moved a long distance since then.

Comment: Good summary of the factors involved. Worth mentioning that time-to-fix takes from seconds (warm start, recent fix) to minutes and, sometimes, 'never' (requiring restart of phone, though this seems to not be an issue with Android 4.1+). Assist-apps such as "GPS Status" can make a huge difference, too.