# Are there any technical limitations as to why GPS can't have a centimetre resolution?

Tags: gps

GPS is not very accurate. I was wondering if this is a technical or economic feasibility problem. If there are no technical barriers, GPS devices with accuracy within 1 centimetre might be possible by 2040. Am assuming this can be achieved with new generation of GPS satellites making use of millimetre wave technology, quantum radar etc
Can anyone please confirm this

Comment: Have a look here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43617/what-is-the-maximum-theoretical-accuracy-of-gps

Comment: I think you're confusing GPS and GNSS. If you're not, then the answer depends on which positioning you're using. Relative positioning is very precise (mm precision), absolute is less precise and real time (the one we have on our phones or on cheap positioning devices. Precision also depends on the location of the receiver in regards to the constellation used, it depends on the number of satellites visible to the receiver...etc. I don't have access right now to my documents, but I can later link some equations explaining how this works.

Comment: @J Monticolo, @user30184 thanks.....the maximum theoretical accuracy of GPS question answers indirectly what I wanted to know